# AndEngine Sprite/Box2D Body removal removes a particluar body (as it should), but removes all instances of the sprite?

Tags: android, box2d, sprite, andengine

I am making a game using Andengine/Box2D physics addon. I experienced the random crashes due to the addition/movement/deletion of box2d bodies during the world step calculation, so I have implemented code to flag sprites/bodies for removal using the setUserData method - I attach a JSON object to each body and sprite that contains the type of sprite, the body, and the sprite itself and its delete status:

```
private JSONObject makeUserData(int type, Body body, Object sprite)
{
    JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();

    try {
        myObject.put("type", type);
        myObject.put("sprite", sprite);
        myObject.put("body", body);
        myObject.put("deleteStatus", false);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Exception creating user data:"+e);
    }
    return myObject;
}
```

then in an update thread iterate through all the bodies in my world looking for these flags and delete the sprites/bodies with the flag. The bodies remove correctly, however the sprite removal seems to delete every instance of that particluar sprite rather than just removing the particular one i flagged to remove! I can tell the bodies are still present without the sprite as my player collides with invisible objects! Here is the code for removal:

```
 private void removeObjectsSetForDestruction()
{
    if(this.mPhysicsWorld!=null)
    {
        Iterator<Body> allMyBodies = this.mPhysicsWorld.getBodies();
        boolean isDelete = false;
        JSONObject currentBodyData;
        while(allMyBodies.hasNext())
        {
             try {
                 currentBodyData = (JSONObject)allMyBodies.next().getUserData();
                 if(currentBodyData!=null)
                 {
                     isDelete = (Boolean) currentBodyData.get("deleteStatus");
                    if(isDelete)
                    {
                        destroyObstruction((Body) currentBodyData.get("body"));
                    }
                 }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Error getting world bodies data:"+e);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void destroyObstruction(Body obstructionBody) throws JSONException
{
    obstructionBody.setActive(false);

        JSONObject secondBodyData = null;
        if(obstructionBody.getUserData()!=null)
        {
            secondBodyData=(JSONObject) obstructionBody.getUserData();

            //explodeObstruction(((IEntity) secondBodyData.get("sprite")).getX(),((IEntity) secondBodyData.get("sprite")).getY());
            if(secondBodyData.get("sprite") instanceof AnimatedSprite)
            {
                removeObject((AnimatedSprite) secondBodyData.get("sprite"));
            }
            else
            {
                removeObject((Sprite) secondBodyData.get("sprite"));
            }
        }


}

private void removeObject(final AnimatedSprite myAnimSprite)
{
    final PhysicsConnector myPhysicsConnector = this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(myAnimSprite);

    this.mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(myPhysicsConnector);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(myPhysicsConnector.getBody());

    this.mScene.unregisterTouchArea(myAnimSprite);
    this.mScene.detachChild(myAnimSprite);

    System.gc();
}

private void removeObject(final Sprite mySprite)
{
    final PhysicsConnector myPhysicsConnector = this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(mySprite);

    this.mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(myPhysicsConnector);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(myPhysicsConnector.getBody());

    this.mScene.unregisterTouchArea(mySprite);
    this.mScene.detachChild(mySprite);

    System.gc();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to take a look at your objects creating code. I assume every sprite has the same `TextureRegion` used, so when the region of one sprite is being changed - same regions on other sprites are being changed too due to Android architecture specifics. For every sprite with same `TextureRegion` you should use `textureRegion.clone()` as the last parameter of the constructor. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer I'll give it a try :) it might be worth noting I think the code has changed from `textureRegion.clone()` to `textureRegion.deepCopy()` (at least thats what it looks like in my version of andengine which I think is the latest one :S)

Comment: Looks like `textureRegion.deepCopy()` did the trick :) thanks again for the pointer!

Comment: @AndroidNoob, You're welcome! And seems I need to update my AndEngine library! =)